# Cancel Android asyncTask progress Dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an android application that employs `AsyncTasks` with progress dialogs.
My problem is that although i have managed to cancel the `AsynchTasks` i get

```
Activity ... has leaked window
```

Its because even though i have managed to cancel the asynchTask i havent cancelled the progress dialog.
how can i guarantee to cancel the asynctasks progress dialog?

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public OnCancelListener buildOnCancelListener(final AsyncTask asyncTask) {
return new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
@Override
public void onCancel(final DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
    asyncTask.cancel(true);
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `yourDialog.dismiss();` in the `onCancelled` method and in `onPostExecute`. If you are using AsyncTask.cancel(...) the onCancelled() will be invoked after doInBackground() NOT onPostExecute().

This is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to move to a new `Activity` without dismissing the Dialog first.

You can try this:

- use `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate()` in `AsyncTask` to update the `ProgressDialog`.
- in `onProgressUpdate()` tests for the dialog to be visible/alive before trying to update it. This will not bring any synchronization issue since `onProgressUpdate` run in the same UI Thread of the activity.
- call `dialog.dismiss()` both on `onCanceled()` and `onPostExecute()`.
- be sure to call `dialog.dismiss()` in `Activity.onStop()` if your dialog is already visible.

Calling `dialog.dismiss()` in `onCancel()` will not guarantee that the problem is solved since

Comment: my onPostExecute() already calls dialog.dismiss. However when you cancel an asyncTask with cancel(true) onPostExecute() will not be called.